# Register a Mac OS Service

Tags: node.js, macos, electron

Mac OS has this feature to have tools called *Services*. They are registered and then available from the `Services` menu in most applications. Also they can be assigned to a global shortcut from the system preferences.

Is there a way to register such a service from `node.js` or electron?

Comment: You need to talk to the OS X native frameworks for that. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/Articles/providing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000853-BABDICBI